# How to install Ubuntu Without turning acpi off

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 19.04, acpi

I brought a laptop worth 2,400$, but I can't even install Ubuntu on it. I have HP Omen 15, RTX 2070 Max Q, 32GB RAM, 12 cores.

I am trying to install the latest version of Ubuntu 19.04 on my laptop. I recently brought this laptop, and I am getting 2-3 types of errors when installing Ubuntu.

[image: Screenshot of error]

I am installing it with Windows 10. I am installing via USB (San Disk). I am getting ACPI Error: No handler or method for GPE...., after clicking on Install Ubuntu in the boot menu.

Last time I got an error like acpi bios error (bug) could not resolve [_SB.PC10.12C2.TPDOJ], A... but the error changed automatically.

Someone suggested me this:

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8rxn.png)

But in this, I need to turn the ACPI off. I don't want to do that. Since it's very important for a laptop, right?

Also even after this solution, I was not getting "Dual boot" option on startup. Windows was loading by default. I had to plugin the san disk pen drive, go to boot menu again, and then start the Ubuntu. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

> But in this, I need to turn the ACPI off. I don't want to do that.

Why not?

> Since it's very important for a laptop, right?

Not really. "important" is a matter of opinion as it depends on what features you want to use on your notebook. You can use a notebook without ACPI.

Mind that the problem is a HARDWARE bug and the boot process nor the installer will be able to fix that. So during installation you turn it off. And after installation you investigate the issue and see if there is a a post-install fix for your issue.

---

ACPI means amongst others: autom. turn off devices like  a monitor, plug+play, setting clock speed from within the OS, stand by modes, power consumption things like that. Again: useful tools sure, but no one could live without. Without ACPI fans runs always so no on the temperature.

It will drain the battery quicker w/o ACPI sure so will affect its lifespan. The alternative is to not install Linux. Again: this is an issue during the initial installation. After that it is a matter of finding the correct tweaks for your specific situation.

Comment: I think ACPI is used for controlling the temperature, battery life? It will negatively affect my battery life right?

Comment: see the edit...

Comment: This hardware bug is only for my laptop? or all laptop using my series (HP OMEN 15 and same spec)?? Can I sue or ask hp for refund

Comment: No. You need to take into account chipset numbers. Not just brand, make, model. Hey nice. I have a HP omen too and that one works flawlessly with Ubuntu. I do use BUDGIE. Maybe try that one? :-) Regarding refund: does HP guarantee 100% support for Linux on that machine? I doubt it has anything else than a windows sticker on it. Again: this is only an issue with installing.

Comment: Are BUDGIE and Ubuntu the same? (same Nvidia Drivers, same commands, and and everything else?)....I don't care about the user interface etc.

Comment: Budgie also throws the same error .This is really frustrating. I can't install Linux, wow. Even my 10 year old laptop can install Linux.

Comment: yes you can: your hardware is broken so turn acpi off during installation.  "Even my 10 year old laptop can install Linux." and what does that mean? older hardware is better for linux. We always lag a few months behind in hardware support since support often comes from examining new hardware and examining drivers. Like I said: I have a HP omen myself. Not a single issue installing 18.04, 18.10, 19.04 and currently rocking 19.10.

Comment: So technically...We both save HP omen 15, and my hardware is facing this problem. So it means, my laptop is wrongly built, which should maybe come under warranty?

Comment: Not unless hp guarantees 100% compatibility for Linux.  Again: your issue is only when installing. Why do you keep ignoring that?

Comment: Ohh...So you mean, I can turn the ACPI off while installing, but turn it again on after installation? In this case, I won't have negative affect on my battery and other things?

Comment: yes. Linux always rebuilds devices on every boot. In the case acpi does not work during normal boot (possibly after updating the system) (but I doubt that it will not work then) you will need to track down why not. Your logs will provide plenty of notifications about it.

Answer (score -1):

**Incase you can't find anything helpful:**

- Install Linux on **Virtual Machine.**
- **OR**
- Enable **Windows Subsystem For Linux(WSL).** Then Download the Distribution you like from **Microsoft Store.**